# How to receive email? Node app/ubuntu server

Tags: node.js, smtp, nodemailer, lmtp

I can setup my node app to send email using nodemailer but I want to be able to receive email to my domain, is there a way that I can do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Nodemailer doesn't support incoming messages - use [mailin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mailin) instead.

It's very powerful - it can check the language of the email and gives it a "spam score".